# Rounding in Tcl

Tags: tcl, rounding

How can I round off a decimal number to the nearest integer in Tcl?

For example, if I enter

- `12.34` as input, the desired output is `12`
- `12.45` as input, the desired output is `12`
- `12.50` as input, the desired output is `13`
- `12.57` as input, the desired output is `13`

and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm) command and for the [round](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm) function.

Basically, it's

```
expr {round($myNum)}
```

Comment: I would also suggest `format "%.0f" $num` but it does not round up for 12.5: `set n 12.5; puts "[format %.0f $n] [expr {round($n)}]"`

Comment: @glennjackman: it does for me, though. `lmap n {0.4 0.5 0.6 1.4 1.5 1.6} {list [format %.0f $n] [expr {round($n)}]}` yields `{0 0} {1 1} {1 1} {1 1} {2 2} {2 2}`.

Comment: oh it suddenly occurs to me, with floating point representation, 12.5 is probably 12.4999999999999

Comment: I'm still getting 13 from your snippet, though.

Comment: huh. I'm on a 64 bit windows system and I get `12 13` from my first comment.

Comment: I'm on a 64-bit Windows 10, but I suspect your Tcl is newer: mine is 8.6.1.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I got the desired result